# how can i run a jar file (java program) on the web?

Tags: java, flash, web, jar

i built a java program with a GUI.
can i upload it to the web and use it without download it or open it as an jar file? i want to put an address at the browser bar and just "play" with my program.

thanks ahead

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for creating a Java Applet and serving that from a Web Server? Then Oracle's documentation for Java Applet's may come in handy: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/

Comment: @JChrist I'm sure in 2016 no browsers support Java applets or even Silverlight. Only Flash remains acceptable... PS: I never tested applets in Safari browser though..

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need to ensure that Java is enabled in your browser. Oracle provides a step-by-step guide on that part [here](https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml). As for your application itself, the project must be compiled as a WebApp. In your HTML code, you will need to use the following code structure, where "xxx" is the width of your applet, and "yyy" is the height:

```
<applet code=Main.class 
    archive="main.jar"
    width="xxx" height="yyy">
</applet>
```

If your Java Applet is not in the same directory as the webpage, you can use the optional "codebase" attribute within your applet tag:

```
<applet code=Main.class 
    ...
    codebase="path/to/applets">
</applet>
```

All said and done, your HTML code may look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <applet code=Main.class 
        archive="main.jar"
        codebase="path/to/applets"
        width="xxx" height="yyy">
    </applet>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you designed your application following good programming principles/patterns (ex: MVC pattern), you have the business logic decoupled from the view layer, so will be able to re-use the business logic in a new web application and deploy it in a web container.

```
[Web]------\
            o------[Business]
[Desktop]--/
```

In desktop you must have used Swing for GUI, in web there are a lot of technologies like JSF, AWT, Angular/Rest, React/Rest, etc.